# Constraints not working properly when iPhone language is Arabic for iOS version 9.0 and 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nslayoutconstraint

When iPhone language is English all the constraints are working fine and properly for every iOS version but when I change the iPhone language to Arabic, views either disappears or goes to negative x coordinates (checked this by view hierarchy debugger) it shows the view's x coordinates is in -values.
and this happens only for iOS Version 9.0 and 9.1 with device language as Arabic.

I have changed the constraints from centre x to leading but it only shows view like this.

[image]

Comment: What help are you looking for with this question? Do you have an MCVE for people to look at? Do you have any code to share?  The question is tagged `objective-c` but there's no code. At the very least you need to show all the constraint definitions and preferably create an MCVE that people can duplicate to look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your constraints for the correct usage of "left / right" vs. "leading / trailing". "Left" means "left" and "right" means "right", always. "Leading" is on the left side for left-to-right text like English, but on the right side for right-to-left text like Arabic. If you mix them up, all kinds of things can go horribly wrong.